# Declaring an array of constant with Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

first i want to apologize for my ignorance,this question may be stupid for many of you..but i am a newbie in the domain of Hw dev
I am trying to turn a software function into a hardware accelerator... 
in the C code we use an array of integer to calculate a certain value as shown here

```
uint k[64] = {
0x428a2f98,0x71374491,0xb5c0fbcf,0xe9b5dba5,0x3956c25b,0x59f111f1,0x923f82a4,0xab1c5ed5, 
0xd807aa98,0x12835b01,0x243185be,0x550c7dc3,0x72be5d74,0x80deb1fe,0x9bdc06a7,0xc19bf174,
0xe49b69c1,0xefbe4786,0x0fc19dc6,0x240ca1cc,0x2de92c6f,0x4a7484aa,0x5cb0a9dc,0x76f988da,
0x983e5152,0xa831c66d,0xb00327c8,0xbf597fc7,0xc6e00bf3,0xd5a79147,0x06ca6351,0x14292967,
0x27b70a85,0x2e1b2138,0x4d2c6dfc,0x53380d13,0x650a7354,0x766a0abb,0x81c2c92e,0x92722c85,
0xa2bfe8a1,0xa81a664b,0xc24b8b70,0xc76c51a3,0xd192e819,0xd6990624,0xf40e3585,0x106aa070,
0x19a4c116,0x1e376c08,0x2748774c,0x34b0bcb5,0x391c0cb3,0x4ed8aa4a,0x5b9cca4f,0x682e6ff3,
0x748f82ee,0x78a5636f,0x84c87814,0x8cc70208,0x90befffa,0xa4506ceb,0xbef9a3f7,0xc67178f2
};
```

as you see here am gonna use it to calculate t1

```
$  t1 = h + EP1(e) + CH(e,f,g) + k[i] + m[i];
```

however am not certain how to declare this array without using registers, i have a verilog file in whitch it uses `localparam` to declare a constant. so i wonder could i use it with this vector as below ?

```
localparam [31:0] k[63:0] =
{0x428a2f98,0x71374491,0xb5c0fbcf,0xe9b5dba5,0x3956c25b,0x59f111f1,0x923f82a4,0xab1c5ed5,
0xd807aa98,0x12835b01,0x243185be,0x550c7dc3,0x72be5d74,0x80deb1fe,0x9bdc06a7,0xc19bf174,
0xe49b69c1,0xefbe4786,0x0fc19dc6,0x240ca1cc,0x2de92c6f,0x4a7484aa,0x5cb0a9dc,0x76f988da,
0x983e5152,0xa831c66d,0xb00327c8,0xbf597fc7,0xc6e00bf3,0xd5a79147,0x06ca6351,0x14292967,
0x27b70a85,0x2e1b2138,0x4d2c6dfc,0x53380d13,0x650a7354,0x766a0abb,0x81c2c92e,0x92722c85,
0xa2bfe8a1,0xa81a664b,0xc24b8b70,0xc76c51a3,0xd192e819,0xd6990624,0xf40e3585,0x106aa070,
0x19a4c116,0x1e376c08,0x2748774c,0x34b0bcb5,0x391c0cb3,0x4ed8aa4a,0x5b9cca4f,0x682e6ff3,
0x748f82ee,0x78a5636f,0x84c87814,0x8cc70208,0x90befffa,0xa4506ceb,0xbef9a3f7,0xc67178f2
};
```

Comment: ah the sha256 constants :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. However, `0x` is not verilog syntax, use `32'h` (or just `'h` if you want it less strongly typed) instead.

```
localparam logic [31:0] k[63:0] =
{
32'h428a2f98,32'h71374491,32'hb5c0fbcf,32'he9b5dba5,32'h3956c25b,32'h59f111f1,32'h923f82a4,32'hab1c5ed5,
32'hd807aa98,32'h12835b01,32'h243185be,32'h550c7dc3,32'h72be5d74,32'h80deb1fe,32'h9bdc06a7,32'hc19bf174,
32'he49b69c1,32'hefbe4786,32'h0fc19dc6,32'h240ca1cc,32'h2de92c6f,32'h4a7484aa,32'h5cb0a9dc,32'h76f988da,
32'h983e5152,32'ha831c66d,32'hb00327c8,32'hbf597fc7,32'hc6e00bf3,32'hd5a79147,32'h06ca6351,32'h14292967,
32'h27b70a85,32'h2e1b2138,32'h4d2c6dfc,32'h53380d13,32'h650a7354,32'h766a0abb,32'h81c2c92e,32'h92722c85,
32'ha2bfe8a1,32'ha81a664b,32'hc24b8b70,32'hc76c51a3,32'hd192e819,32'hd6990624,32'hf40e3585,32'h106aa070,
32'h19a4c116,32'h1e376c08,32'h2748774c,32'h34b0bcb5,32'h391c0cb3,32'h4ed8aa4a,32'h5b9cca4f,32'h682e6ff3,
32'h748f82ee,32'h78a5636f,32'h84c87814,32'h8cc70208,32'h90befffa,32'ha4506ceb,32'hbef9a3f7,32'hc67178f2
};
```

Comment: FYI- constant array literals require SystemVerilog support.

Comment: of course i just overlooked the 0x ..thank you ery much

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off going with an **integer** type rather than localparam. Logic types are 4-state, which is more expensive on the simulator and since you are using it as a constant value (I assume), you should be fine with integer.

```
integer k[64] = {
32'h428a2f98,32'h71374491,32'hb5c0fbcf,32'he9b5dba5,32'h3956c25b,32'h59f111f1,32'h923f82a4,32'hab1c5ed5,
32'hd807aa98,32'h12835b01,32'h243185be,32'h550c7dc3,32'h72be5d74,32'h80deb1fe,32'h9bdc06a7,32'hc19bf174,
32'he49b69c1,32'hefbe4786,32'h0fc19dc6,32'h240ca1cc,32'h2de92c6f,32'h4a7484aa,32'h5cb0a9dc,32'h76f988da,
32'h983e5152,32'ha831c66d,32'hb00327c8,32'hbf597fc7,32'hc6e00bf3,32'hd5a79147,32'h06ca6351,32'h14292967,
32'h27b70a85,32'h2e1b2138,32'h4d2c6dfc,32'h53380d13,32'h650a7354,32'h766a0abb,32'h81c2c92e,32'h92722c85,
32'ha2bfe8a1,32'ha81a664b,32'hc24b8b70,32'hc76c51a3,32'hd192e819,32'hd6990624,32'hf40e3585,32'h106aa070,
32'h19a4c116,32'h1e376c08,32'h2748774c,32'h34b0bcb5,32'h391c0cb3,32'h4ed8aa4a,32'h5b9cca4f,32'h682e6ff3,
32'h748f82ee,32'h78a5636f,32'h84c87814,32'h8cc70208,32'h90befffa,32'ha4506ceb,32'hbef9a3f7,32'hc67178f2
};
```

Comment: Declaring the array size with `[64]` works in SystemVerilog. Verilog needs to specify lsb and msb indexes. `integer k[0:63]` is the Verilog equivalent.